# Prove that $\bigcup\mathcal F$ and $\bigcup\mathcal G$ are disjoint iff for all $A\in\mathcal F$ and $B\in\mathcal G$, $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing, solution-verification

Not a duplicate of

[Suppose $F$ and $G$ are families of sets.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/815498/suppose-f-and-g-are-families-of-sets)

[Prove $\bigcup\mathcal{F}$ and $\bigcup\mathcal{G}$ are disjoint iff for all $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $B \in \mathcal{G}$, A and B are disjoint.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3711990/prove-bigcup-mathcalf-and-bigcup-mathcalg-are-disjoint-iff-for-all-a)

This is exercise $3.4.19$ from the book *How to Prove it* by Velleman $($$2^{nd}$ edition$)$:

Suppose $\mathcal F$ and $\mathcal G$ are families of sets. Prove that $\bigcup\mathcal F$ and $\bigcup\mathcal G$ are disjoint iff for all $A\in\mathcal F$ and $B\in\mathcal G$, $A$ and $B$ are disjoint.

Here is my proof:

$(\rightarrow)$ Suppose $(\bigcup\mathcal F)\cap(\bigcup\mathcal G)=\emptyset$. Let $A$ be an arbitrary element of $\mathcal F$ and $B$ be an arbitrary element of $\mathcal G$. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $A$. Since $A\in\mathcal F$ and $x\in A$, $x\in\bigcup\mathcal F$. From $(\bigcup\mathcal F)\cap(\bigcup\mathcal G)=\emptyset$ and $x\in\bigcup\mathcal F$, $x\notin \bigcup\mathcal G$. From $x\notin \bigcup\mathcal G$ and $B\in \mathcal G$, $x\notin B$. Thus if $x\in A$ then $x\notin B$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $\forall x(x\in A\rightarrow\ x\notin B)$ and so $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Since $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary, $\forall A\in\mathcal F\forall B\in\mathcal G(A\cap B=\emptyset)$. Therefore if
$(\bigcup\mathcal F)\cap(\bigcup\mathcal G)=\emptyset$ then $\forall A\in\mathcal F\forall B\in\mathcal G(A\cap B=\emptyset)$.

$(\leftarrow)$ Suppose $\forall A\in\mathcal F\forall B\in\mathcal G(A\cap B=\emptyset)$. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $\bigcup\mathcal F$. This means $A\in\mathcal F$ and $x\in A$. Let $B$ be an arbitrary element of $\mathcal G$. From $\forall A\in\mathcal F\forall B\in\mathcal G(A\cap B=\emptyset)$ and $A\in\mathcal F$, $\forall B\in\mathcal G(A\cap B=\emptyset)$. From $\forall B\in\mathcal G(A\cap B=\emptyset)$ and $B\in\mathcal G$, $A\cap B=\emptyset$. From $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and $x\in A$, $x\notin B$. Thus if $B\in \mathcal G$ then $x\notin B$. Since $B$ is arbitrary, $\forall B(B\in\mathcal G\rightarrow x\notin B)$ and so $x\notin \bigcup\mathcal G$. Thus if $x\in\bigcup\mathcal F$ then $x\notin\bigcup\mathcal G$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $\forall x(x\in\bigcup\mathcal F\rightarrow x\notin\bigcup\mathcal G)$ and so $(\bigcup\mathcal F)\cap(\bigcup\mathcal G)=\emptyset$. Therefore if $\forall A\in\mathcal F\forall B\in\mathcal G(A\cap B=\emptyset)$ then $(\bigcup\mathcal F)\cap(\bigcup\mathcal G)=\emptyset$.

Since $\Bigr((\bigcup\mathcal F)\cap(\bigcup\mathcal G)=\emptyset\Bigr)$ $\rightarrow$ $\Bigr(\forall A\in\mathcal F\forall B\in\mathcal G(A\cap B=\emptyset)\Bigr)$ and $\Bigr(\forall A\in\mathcal F\forall B\in\mathcal G(A\cap B=\emptyset)\Bigr)$ $\rightarrow$ $\Bigr((\bigcup\mathcal F)\cap(\bigcup\mathcal G)=\emptyset\Bigr)$, $\Bigr((\bigcup\mathcal F)\cap(\bigcup\mathcal G)=\emptyset\Bigr)$ iff $\Bigr(\forall A\in\mathcal F\forall B\in\mathcal G(A\cap B=\emptyset)\Bigr)$. $Q.E.D.$

Is my proof valid$?$

Thanks for your attention.

**Edit:**

$(\leftarrow)$ Suppose $\forall A\in\mathcal F\forall B\in\mathcal G(A\cap B=\emptyset)$. Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $\bigcup\mathcal F$. So we can choose some $A_0$ such that $A_0\in\mathcal F$ and $x\in A_0$. Let $B$ be an arbitrary element of $\mathcal G$. From $\forall A\in\mathcal F\forall B\in\mathcal G(A\cap B=\emptyset)$ and $A_0\in\mathcal F$, $\forall B\in\mathcal G(A_0\cap B=\emptyset)$. From $\forall B\in\mathcal G(A_0\cap B=\emptyset)$ and $B\in\mathcal G$, $A_0\cap B=\emptyset$. From $A_0\cap B=\emptyset$ and $x\in A_0$, $x\notin B$. Thus if $B\in \mathcal G$ then $x\notin B$. Since $B$ is arbitrary, $\forall B(B\in\mathcal G\rightarrow x\notin B)$ and so $x\notin \bigcup\mathcal G$. Thus if $x\in\bigcup\mathcal F$ then $x\notin\bigcup\mathcal G$. Since $x$ is arbitrary, $\forall x(x\in\bigcup\mathcal F\rightarrow x\notin\bigcup\mathcal G)$ and so $(\bigcup\mathcal F)\cap(\bigcup\mathcal G)=\emptyset$. Therefore if $\forall A\in\mathcal F\forall B\in\mathcal G(A\cap B=\emptyset)$ then $(\bigcup\mathcal F)\cap(\bigcup\mathcal G)=\emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s just a bit more detailed than is probably necessary even at this stage, but with one small exception it’s correct. I would make one change: in the second half, after you let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $\bigcup\mathscr{F}$, you say that ‘[t]his means $A\in\mathscr{F}$ and $x\in A$’. That’s not quite right: what it actually means (and what you should say) is that **there is** some $A\in\mathscr{F}$ **such that** $x\in A$. (In fact, what you wrote **couldn’t** be right, simply because it makes an assertion about something that has not at that point been introduced, namely, the set $A$.)

Comment: Could you please check the edit and say if is it correct now?

Comment: @XBaghizadeh: Yep, that fixes it. How detailed a proof should be depends in large part on the intended audience: the more experienced the audience, the less detail is necessary. But too much detail can make an argument hard to read even for an inexperienced audience. Here, for instance, I would probably just say something like this: Let $x\in\bigcup\mathscr{F}$. Then there is an $A_0\in\mathscr{F}$ such that $x\in A_0$. For each $B\in\mathscr{G}$ we know that $A_0\cap B=\varnothing$ and hence that $x\notin B$. Thus, $x\notin B$ for each $B\in\mathscr{G}$, so $x\notin\bigcup\mathscr{G}$. ...

Comment: ... Since $x$ was an arbitrary member of $\bigcup\mathscr{F}$, it follows that $(\bigcup\mathscr{F})\cap\bigcup\mathscr{G}=\varnothing$.